# Java custom exception handling in class

Tags: java, exception

I'm working with netbeans and i created this exception class:

```
public class VehicleException extends Exception{
    private String matricula;
    private Calendar dataMatricula;
    private ModelVehicle model;

    private int causa;

        public VehicleException(int causa, Object valor) throws Exception {
        this.causa = causa;
        switch (causa) {
            case 1:
                dataMatricula = (Calendar) valor;
                break;
            case 2:
                matricula = (String) valor;
                break;
            case 3:
                model = (ModelVehicle) valor;
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception("Utilització errònia en construir VehicleException. Causa: " + causa);
        }
    }

         @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        switch (causa) {
            case 1:
                return "dataMatricula erroni: " + dataMatricula + " Ha de contenir valor";
            case 2:
                return "matricula erroni: " + matricula + " Ha de contenir valor";
            case 3:
                return "Model erroni: " + model + " Ha de contenir valor";
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
```

And I'm working with this kind of exception in my class "Vehicle" :

```
public class Vehicle implements Comparable<Vehicle> {

    private String matricula;
    private ModelVehicle model;
    private Calendar dataMatricula;


     public Vehicle(String matricula, ModelVehicle model, Calendar dataMatricula) throws VehicleException {
        setMatricula(matricula);
        setDataMatricula(dataMatricula);
        setModelVehicle(model);


    }


     public String getMatricula(){
         return matricula;
     }

     public ModelVehicle getModelVehicle(){
         return model;
     }
     public Calendar getDataMatricula(){
         return dataMatricula;
     }


      public final void setMatricula(String matricula) throws VehicleException {
        if (matricula == null || matricula.compareTo("") == 0) {
            throw new VehicleException(2,matricula);
        }
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

      public void setModelVehicle(ModelVehicle model) throws VehicleException{
          if(model == null){
             throw new VehicleException(3,model);
          }
          else {
              this.model = model;
          }
      }

      public void setDataMatricula(Calendar c) throws VehicleException{
          if(c == null){
             throw new VehicleException(1,c);
          }
          this.dataMatricula = c;
      }
```

The problem cones when i try to compile,in the setter methods i get this message :

> error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to
>   be thrown
>               throw new VehicleException(2,matricula); C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\Examen
>   isidrer\M03-uf5\Exmaenm03uf5\src\info\infomila\Vehicle.java:55: error:
>   unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be
>   thrown
>                throw new VehicleException(3,model); C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\Examen
>   isidrer\M03-uf5\Exmaenm03uf5\src\info\infomila\Vehicle.java:64: error:
>   unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be
>   thrown
>                throw new VehicleException(1,c);

I don't quite undestand why this is happening, crearly the setter methods have a "throws VehicleException".

Answer (score 5):

The constructor for `VehicleException` can throw an exception itself:

```
public VehicleException(int causa, Object valor) throws Exception {
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This means your calling scope would need to handle/rethrow that exception from the constructor, or you could choose to [suppress the exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed-java.lang.Throwable-) rather than throwing it.

```
default:
    super.addSuppressed(new Exception("Utilització errònia en construir VehicleException. Causa: " + causa));
```

Comment: From the message passed to the `Exception` constructor i'd usually tend to throw a `RuntimeException` here.

Comment: @Izruo If they throw a `RuntimeException`, then the `VehicleException` would never be seen, so this allows both exceptions to appear in the error log.

Comment: My point is that an `Exception` is normally `suppressed` when it is caused due to some other `Exception` being thrown. This one here will be thrown when a programmer uses a wrong constant in his code (which in this case is throwing the `Exception`). But when it comes to logging, you've got a point here.